# Firebase Remote Config Unexpectedly Found Nil while unwrapping error configValue(forKey:)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am using remote config in my IOS app to set a few values such as the name, image name, and other things. Last week, the same code was working but without any changes, it is now giving me this error: "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file "

Here is the code that is giving me this error. I followed this tutorial:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3mDzJoDJIqc from the Firecasts series.

```
 func setUpRemoteConfigDefaults() {
    let remoteConfigDefaultValues = [ "mp1Img1" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Img2" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Img3" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Img4" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Points" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Name" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Description" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Logo" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1WebsiteCompany" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1Company" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1WebsiteToPurchase" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1AddProdImg1" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1AddProdImg2" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1AddProdImg3" : "elcap" as NSObject,
                                      "mp1AddProdImg4" : "elcap" as NSObject
    ]
    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults(remoteConfigDefaultValues)
    
}

func fetchRemoteConfig() {
    //FIXME Remove this frist line
    let debugSettings = RemoteConfigSettings(developerModeEnabled: true)
    RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().fetch(withExpirationDuration: 0) { [unowned self] (status, error) in
        
        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
        
        RemoteConfig.remoteConfig().activateFetched()
        self.updateViewWithRCValues()
    }
}

func updateViewWithRCValues() {
    
    let rc = RemoteConfig.remoteConfig()

    
    let M1IMG1 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1Img1").stringValue!)!
    let M1IMG2 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1Img2").stringValue!)!
    let M1IMG3 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mpImg3").stringValue!)!
    let M1IMG4 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mpImg4").stringValue!)!
    let PVID = ""
    let POINTS = rc.configValue(forKey: "mpPoints").stringValue!
    let NAME = rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1Name").stringValue!
    let DESC = rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1Description").stringValue!
    let LOGO = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mp\(i)Logo").stringValue!)!
    let CWEB = rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1WebsiteCompany").stringValue!
    let CNAME = rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1Company").stringValue!
    let PROMO = ""
    let PWEB = rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1WebsiteToPurchase").stringValue!
    let ADD1 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mpAddProdImg1").stringValue!)!
    let ADD2 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1AddProdImg2").stringValue!)!
    let ADD3 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1AddProdImg3").stringValue!)!
    let ADD4 = UIImage(named: rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1AddProdImg4").stringValue!)!
    
        
    }
}
```

MY FIREBASE REMOTE CONFIG SETUP:

[image: Here is the Remote Config in FB]

[image: MY ERROR]

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are force unwrapping a string and than an image. Are you sure remote config is nil? It says "file" in your pasted error message.

- First make sure that the file exists in your asset catalog with the name you require.
- Second, check the value in Firebase console, and make sure it does not have any unexpected characters.

If you copy pasted the value, probably there is a tab, space or another invisible character left behind.

**EDIT:** You can try something like this for the first image where you are getting the error:

```swift
guard let name = rc.configValue(forKey: "mp1Img1").stringValue else {
  print("Remote config is nil for mp1Img1")
  return
}

guard let image = UIImage(named: name) else {
  print("Image named \(name) does not exist in asset catalog.")
  return
}
```

First guard will be a control for nil remote config value.
Second for a possible missing image. You can always add a breakpoint to see what the values are.

Comment: sorry, I am a bit confused about "file". what am i supposed to be looking for specifically? (this may be a dumb question)